# Calculating PSNR MP3 - Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935900/psnr-for-audio-signal-in-matlab) I'm struggling to get the code working in order to calculate the PSNR.

The error I get is "Matrix dimensions must agree".

Here is the code:

```
[y1,fs1]=audioread('track.mp3');
[y2,fs2]=audioread('track.mp3');
[c1x,c1y]=size(y1);
[c2x,c2y]=size(y1);


 R=c1x;
 C=c1y;
 %err = sum((y1-y2).^2)/(R*C);
 err = sum((y1-y2)/(R*C));
 MSE=sqrt(err);
 MAXVAL=65535;
  PSNR = 20*log10(MAXVAL/MSE); 
  disp(['mse=' num2str(MSE) ' PSNR=' num2str(PSNR)]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PSNR for audio signal in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935900/psnr-for-audio-signal-in-matlab)

Comment: @yms yes, but it concerns a different problem. That's the original question I've linked at the start of my question

Comment: Given that the full error message (which you haven't provided, hint hint...) tells you exactly where the error is you could probably start by looking at the dimensions of the arrays you're attempting to divide/multiply/square/whoknowswhat and make sure you're trying to do something that's mathematically valid.

Comment: You said: The error I get is "Matrix dimensions must agree". That's the same error of the original question.